# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method with(Landroid/content/Context;)

Tags: java, android, picasso, android-multidex, matisse

Hi I am trying to use the https://github.com/Swati4star/Images-to-PDF ImagesToPDF function from this library. I have added all the classes required in my application.

Now I have used picasso in my application before adding the ImagesToPDF function.

Now after adding it I am getting following error :

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method with(Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso; in class Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.squareup.picasso.Picasso' appears in /data/app/com.example.onboardingversion2-sJCkixxNOR2KPNLmYYdvpQ==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
```

Getting error in following function :

```
    /**
 * Opens Matisse activity to select Images
 */
private void selectImages() {
    Matisse.from(this)
            .choose(MimeType.ofImage(), false)
            .countable(true)
            .capture(true)
            .captureStrategy(new CaptureStrategy(true, AUTHORITY_APP))
            .maxSelectable(1000)
            .imageEngine(new PicassoEngine())
            .forResult(INTENT_REQUEST_GET_IMAGES);
}
```

app gets crashed and gives error. I added application and set Multidex

```
    public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(base);
    }
}
```

I also added multidexEnabled true in gradle. Still its throwing the error.
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: have you define application class in manifest file ?

Comment: yes i did. @HemantParmar

Comment: Update your picasso gradle version and check.

Comment: I have added latest version of picasso @HemantParmar

Answer (score 1):

Picasso in not updated for about 4 years, it has many issues. Maybe You should switch to [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Comment: I changed new PicassoEngine() to new GlideEngine it still throws same error.

Comment: try this:    implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0") {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
  }

Comment: You've added this line or replaced previous GlideEngine?

Comment: Added library in dependencies and replaced PicassoEngine with GlideEngine

Comment: please look here: [issue in Glide with same error](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2796). Maybe you'll find answer there

Comment: I am not using support libraries, I am using androidx. Is this error coming because of that? I tried adding   annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.databinding:adapters:3.3.2'
    implementation 'com.android.databinding:library:3.3.2'   still it does not work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line

```
.imageEngine(new PicassoEngine())
```

where PicassoEngine() class uses Picasso.with(context).... module which is deprecated. The solution is you have to create a new class, name it NewPicassoEngine() as below;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.zhihu.matisse.engine.ImageEngine;

public class NewPicassoEngine implements ImageEngine {

@Override
public void loadThumbnail(Context context, int resize, Drawable placeholder, ImageView imageView, Uri uri) {
    Picasso.get().load(uri).placeholder(placeholder)
            .resize(resize, resize)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(imageView);
}

@Override
public void loadGifThumbnail(Context context, int resize, Drawable placeholder, ImageView imageView,
                             Uri uri) {
    loadThumbnail(context, resize, placeholder, imageView, uri);
}

@Override
public void loadImage(Context context, int resizeX, int resizeY, ImageView imageView, Uri uri) {
    Picasso.get().load(uri).resize(resizeX, resizeY).priority(Picasso.Priority.HIGH)
            .centerInside().into(imageView);
}

@Override
public void loadGifImage(Context context, int resizeX, int resizeY, ImageView imageView, Uri uri) {
    loadImage(context, resizeX, resizeY, imageView, uri);
}

@Override
public boolean supportAnimatedGif() {
    return false;
}}
```

and use it as;

```
private void selectImages() {
Matisse.from(this)
        .choose(MimeType.ofImage(), false)
        .countable(true)
        .capture(true)
        .captureStrategy(new CaptureStrategy(true, AUTHORITY_APP))
        .maxSelectable(1000)
        .imageEngine(new NewPicassoEngine())
        .forResult(INTENT_REQUEST_GET_IMAGES);
}
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**GlideEngine()** work for me using latest dependency

```
     fun selectImages(frag: Fragment?, requestCode: Int) {
        Matisse.from(frag)
            .choose(MimeType.ofImage(), false)
            .countable(true)
            .capture(true)
            .captureStrategy(CaptureStrategy(true, AUTHORITY_APP))
            .maxSelectable(1000)
            .imageEngine(GlideEngine())
            .forResult(requestCode)
    }
```